Docker local installation gives me "Invalid Host header" text in browser window
I am running Docker from docker compose on the local environment. When trying to access the "client" part (react) I get "Invalid Hose Header" in the browser visiting the localhost:3050. Here is my docker compose setup:
version: '3'
services: 

  postgres: 
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    volumes:
      - .tmp/pg-dev-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: dbdev

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - server
      - client
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'


  server:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app:delegated
    env_file:
      - ./server/config/dev.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development


  worker:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/app:delegated
    env_file:
      - ./worker/config/dev.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
  

  client:
    depends_on:
      - server
      - postgres
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app

The trafic is routed via NGINX. The setup for NGINX is following:
FROM nginx
COPY ./default-dev.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Config file for the NGINX is:
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream server {
  server server:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://server;
  }
}

NGINX log is giving me 200 reply, but the instead of showing the react app it shows me white screen with the following text: "Invalid Host header".
Whole setup is working perfectly fine on production server, but NOT on local. :)
I hope someone was experiencing similar issue and was able to find way around it.

Is your application configured to require a specific Host: header in the request?

After conversation with DevOps I have amended the Dockerfile for the client and added following:
      - DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true 

This is only for the local environment and is not suitable for the production. Since our production did not suffer such problem I am fine with this solution.
